# Javascript Display/hide pictures

Tags: javascript

How to remove(hide) pictures when a certain picture is displayed based on their IDs. This is what I got so far:

```
function setImageinVisible(id) {
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    img.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the good practice says, you shouldn't mess with object's styles directly but rather toggle it's classes (because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). My advice is to create a state class like

```
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

and then just toggle this class on particular element with jquery, pure JS or something else, for ex.

```
$('.my-image').addClass('is-hidden') // to hide
$('.my-image').removeClass('is-hidden') // to show
```

with pure JS:

```
document.querySelector('.my-image').classList.add('is-hidden')
document.querySelector('.my-image').classList.remove('is-hidden')
```

**UPDATE:**

To reset previous state (set all images as hidden), before showing one:

```
// to add.is-hidden from every image (to hide all the images)
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'), function(el) {
    el.classList.add('is-hidden');
});
// to show choosen image
document.querySelector('.my-image').removeClass('is-hidden')
```

Comment: Hmm, I don`t use jquery, how does it look in JavaScript ? ^^

Comment: Is it possible to set all pictures hidden when a picture is displayed based on map areas ? So when you click on an area only the associated pictures will display.  This is the full code ->  https://jsfiddle.net/kc1sf8qL/

Comment: Not sure did I understood you well, but I think the answer is YES - take a look at the update.

Comment: Do i put these codes below my function, right ? And this one is css .is-hidden {
  display: none;
}   ?

Comment: Yes, just modify the selectors properly. If it did help you  a bit, please accept the answer as well.

Comment: Ok, but why did you write document.querySelector('.my-image').removeClass('is-hidden'). I mean ('.my-image') ?

Comment: in place of .my-image could be any choosen selector - it can be the one passed as ID for example - it's just a generic example.

Comment: Hmm, can't see whats wrong.  https://jsfiddle.net/hhz0y341/6/  Still doesnt work. All pictures are displayed.

Comment: Read about selectors document.querySelectorAll('id') - is not a proper value for it. Selectors are wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Note: `toggle-vader-button`, `("#Vader")`, and `("#Palpatine")` are all based on a project I'm working on. Substitute the IDs of your photos in

```
$ (document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggle-vader-button").on("click", function () {
        $("#Vader").toggle();
        $("#Palpatine").toggle();
    });
});
```

As one is toggled off, another is toggled on. Also note that I have Palpatine's display as "none" in my CSS so it switches on whilst Vader switches off. Both will occupy the same space also.